# How to get store value from LLVM IR?

Tags: clang, llvm

I am writing an optimization for my compiler and I use LLVM IR as my Intermediate Language. I have converted my .c file to LLVM IR. How to get the value 10 from the line `store i32 10, i32* %1, align 4` ?

Answer (score 0):

To find this value, you need to traverse through hierarchy Module -> Function -> Instruction - > Value.

If you make Module pass, then first you should find right function, by iterating your module by (example on legacy pass):

```
bool YourPass::runOnModule(Module &Mod) {
    for (Function &Fn : Mod) {
```

Choose right function, probably by comparing name (calling Fn.getName()). If your pass is a Function one, this step is unnecessary, you have Fn as parameter.

Iterate other instructions of this function and choose "store" one:

```
for (Instruction &I : instructions(Fn)) {
    if (StoreInst *SI = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)) //Probably some additional condition to select exact one
```

Then get parameter: Value* YourVal = SI->getOperand(0);

Like this!

Comment: thank you so much! It works. changed as 'dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)'. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!)) Of cause some includes are required.